# Adding data files to a mac .app made from PyInstaller or Py2App

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, py2app, .app

I am trying to add exactly eight `.png` files and one `.json` file to a `.app` I am trying to create using PyInstaller, or, if I have to, I can use Py2App. The program I am trying to turn to a `.app` is a tkinter GUI application, if that's relevant in any way.

With PyInstaller I can get the `.app` to form correctly by doing

```
pyi-makespec --windowed --icon myicon.icns myapp.py
```

then adding the files under the `datas` attribute in the [`.spec`](http://pastebin.com/tM2H4Fw4) file, and then finally doing

```
pyinstaller myapp.spec
```

However, when I run the program its raising a python error saying it can't locate the files, even though I checked inside the `.app` and they are there. While troubleshooting, I tried doing `print(os.getcwd())` and it said it was in `/User/Robert`, which I presume is the problem (the `.app` is not located in that directory).

As for using Py2App, I can't even figure out how to properly add the files. I tried

```
py2applet --make-setup --iconfile myicon.icns myapp.py
```

and then added all their paths within the generated `DATA_FILES` list, but I just get an error while it is forming the `.app` after executing

```
python3 setup.py py2app
```

So if anybody knows how I can form a `.app` file from a tkinter application that makes use of certain files, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using python 3.5.1 (for both the `.py` file being converted and the conversion process) and my mac OS X version is 10.11, if that helps in any way.

PPS: I have been able to get this exact same program to work on windows in the form of a `.exe` (converted using PyInstaller).

Comment: You might want to post your `spec` file, as there could be some clues there.

Comment: @l'L'l I've added a link to a pastebin containing the `.spec` file's content.

Comment: The one strange thing about your `app = BUNDLE` statement is it's using a `coll` instead of `exe`... maybe try changing that. Also you might want to define a workpath in your `pyi-makespec` command and set the icon like `--icon=myicon.icns`...

Comment: @l'L'l Ok, I'll give that a try. How do I define a workpath?

Comment: It would be the directory that you are building from `–workpath=/path/of/files/to/build`... it's not really necessary. but it might help find the files.